# Is there a good resource to find out if an industrial controls component is branded by more than one company, and who actually manufactures it?

Tags: control-engineering, industrial-engineering

I have seen multiple components such as relays, circuit protection, plcs, terminals blocks, and even enclosures that were sold by completely different companies.  Other than the writing on the device, such as model number and obviously company name; the components are identical.  After some research I discovered that the identical components all had the same source.

Is there a resource that can help me determine when this is the case?

Currently I have some Phoenix Contact terminal blocks and Controllers.  I am having difficulty finding replacements and support, so I was wondering if they were manufactured by a different company which would give me a new lead to track them down.  Specifically the ILC 151 ETH controller at the moment.  Does Phoenix Contact manufacture this?  If they do, did any other company rebrand it and sell it under their name?

It would be great to find some information on that controller, but I run into this often with legacy products.  So, it would be even better to find a resource that cross-references multiple types of components across multiple manufacturers/companies.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This type of commodity selling is called badge building. Sometimes the products are identical, but there is a chance that different companies request different QC/Binning for the product that they are selling.
If it's something like a controller, badge building might also mean that the software needed to program them might be different, even if they have the same form factor.

Supply chain verification is also a big thing in the critical manufacturing industry. Newer Industrial controllers(Lets say Rockwell 1756-L8 series) come with chain of custody certificates and even have supplier verification built into their programming software, to brick out of supply chain processors(Think smuggled, illegally purchased, stolen).